# How can I align my navbar items to the left and right side of the centered image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, blazor, bootstrap-5

I'm developing a website in Blazor with Bootstrap version 5.1. So I set an image within that navbar. Now I want to align the other items of the navbar just before and after the image in the center. I tried using the Bootstrap 5.0 `ms-auto` and `me-auto` to a div and put the nav items in it, but it only aligned the items to the right or left corner of the navbar.

Here is the code of the website:

```
@page "/"

<style>
    .navbar {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 0;
        opacity: 80%
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        display: block;
        
    }

    .img-responsive {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 156px;
        max-width: 250px;
        top: 109px;
    }

    .circle
    {
    width: 249px;
    height: 285px;
    border-radius:250px;
    font-size:50px;
    line-height:500px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000
    }
    body {
        background: url(assets/hack2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>

<div class=bodyContainer>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="circle bg-light navbar-brand">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img class="img-responsive navbar-brand" src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
            </div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Über uns</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Aktuelles</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Genossenschaft</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Nochagfrogt</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Kontakt</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

If it helps (because I created a container class for the body):

```
.bodyContainer {
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

Comment: You are not meant to put inline styles into a `.razor` page.  Blazor has a particular way that you should include `.css` in your project.  You should find some tutorial to learn the basics to get started.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I guess with the "particular way" you mean that I could add a <link href> to the index.html to give all my razor components access to a defined stylesheet. I just did that for the .bodycontainer. Everything I learned about Blazor was at work. We define styles there in all possible ways. Through extra stylesheets, the style section at the beginning of a razor page, bootstrap classes and inline styles. I know it can be ugly to do it like that. But you know, there are many ways to solve a problem. Even with styles :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your `.navbar-nav a` font-color black just so I could see it better, and added `white-space: nowrap;` on your `navbar-nav` class so your words don't break when resizing. I am not sure if I properly understood what you wanted your end result to be, but I think I got the gist of it.

For this to work with the ease of customization in the future, I suggest splitting each side into two separate divs, as I did below. `.left` containing the left side nav components, and `.right` containing the right components. I put a `flex-display` on your two new divs dividing the components, and spaced them out using `gap`. Then I nested them in a parent `nav element` which I called `same-line` for demonstration purposes.

First, add a `flex-display` then you can add `justify-content: space-around;` on your parent `nav` that allows for the two sides to space evenly to both the **left** and **right** sides respectfully. If your logo is truly the size of the `.circle` class, I added a sample `media-query` so the `font-size` of the nav components gets smaller and doesn't overlap the logo.

```css
.navbar {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 0;
        opacity: 80%;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        display: block;
        
    }

    .img-responsive {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 156px;
        max-width: 250px;
        top: 109px;
    }

    .circle {
    width: 249px;
    height: 285px;
    border-radius:250px;
    font-size:50px;
    line-height:500px;
    text-align:center;
    background: black;
    }
    

.navbar-nav a {
  color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* additions */
 .left {
   display: flex;
   gap: 20px;
 }
 
  .right {
   display: flex;
   gap: 20px;
 }
 
 
 nav.same-line {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .same-line {
    font-size: smaller;
  }
  
  .left, .right {
    display: flex;
    gap: 5px;
  }
}

/* additions END */

    body {
        background: url(assets/hack2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<div class="bodyContainer">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="circle bg-light navbar-brand">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img class="img-responsive navbar-brand" src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
            </div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <nav class="same-line"> <!-- puts both .left & .right one same line -->
            <div class="navbar-nav left">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Über uns</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Aktuelles</a>
            </div>
            <!-- left contains leftside nav components, right = opposite -->
            <div class="navbar-nav right">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Genossenschaft</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Nochagfrogt</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Kontakt</a>
            </div>          
        </nav>    

            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Click **full-page** when testing the snippet, and resize your browser to watch the `font-size` change just before it overlaps. I would target this same `media-query` to change your logo size when resizing also.